# static text - rounded rectangle border mfc

Tags: static, mfc

I have a static control in a dialog to show some messages in a dialog. By default it is as rectangle box. I want to make it as rounded corned rectangle to get good appearance, similar to that of a button. Any properties can be changed to make it as rounded corner rectangle

Comment: There is no such thing. You need to the painting yourself.

Comment: Here is a sample for a button. Statics wouldn't be much more complicated... https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67/Round-Buttons-2